# Commutative diagram using TikZ

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{rr}\arrow{dr} &              & B \arrow{rr}\arrow{dl} & & C \\
                       & D \arrow{dr}                                \\
                       &              & E
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

In the above code, how do I draw an arrow from C to E?

Comment: Thanks @marmot for your reply, but it does not work....

Comment: I edited your code so now you can guess the direction for the desired arrow.

Comment: By the way, there is an extra column unnecessary before `C`. Your diagram could have four columns, so three `&` is enough.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `\arrow[ddll]`.

Here's a version with parallel arrows, due to the `between origins` specification. I added an example where the objects are wider; you may want to increase the column separation, but you have to decide it only after seeing the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={3em,between origins}]
A \arrow[rr]\arrow[dr] &&
B \arrow[rr] \arrow[dl,dashed] &&
C \arrow[ddll] \\
& D \\
&& E \arrow[ul]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={3em,between origins}]
\bigoplus_i A_i \arrow[rr]\arrow[dr] &&
\prod_j B_j \arrow[rr] \arrow[dl,dashed] &&
C \arrow[ddll] \\
& D \\
&& E \arrow[ul]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, much better than my answer (which I did not mean to write anyway). +1